# How to prevent Tauri app from opening remote links

Tags: javascript, rust, webview, configuration, tauri

I made a Tauri Hello world app, using react-ts, and that contained logos for Tauri, Vite,  and React, that are clickable of course, it uses an `a` HTML tag like `<a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">`, which if I click on it, opens a new tab in my default browser that loads that URL.

So naturally, I wanted to test if Tauri apps would open that link (or any other remote URL actually) inside the app's webview, so I changed that to `<a href="https://vitejs.dev">` which did just that.

What I want to know is: how to configure any Tauri app to not open / load any URLs unless I specifically allow it to?

What I tried already:

- I tried changing the CSP option in the `tauri.conf.json` file to none to not allow any remote scripts or ....

```
"security": {
      "csp": {
        "default-src": ["'none'"]
      }
    },
```

- I also tried searching for some kind of `allowed-navigation` option that someone talked about
- I also started looking into a `before-navigate` hook in the `main.rs` file but i don't know how to implement it

I would really appreciate it if you explain how to reach my objective, and I would be even more indebted to you if you can give me same better options or the ones more appropriate for a production ready app.

Regards,
*zk*.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by using Remark/[Rehype](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-external-links) plugins during the bundling.

```
import rehypeExternalLinks from 'rehype-external-links';

...
rehypePlugins: [[rehypeExternalLinks, { target: '_blank' }]]
...
```